# Swing JTextArea cannot show font type and color

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am developing a spam detector application using Java GUI (NetBeans). Now I have a simple user interface which includes a text area in which the user is going to paste his email in to order to check if its a spam or not, but the problem is when you paste a text in the text area all the text properties will be lost such as : Font type, color, hyperlinks etc...

So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need RTF-enabled Swing component to visualize various text properties.

**`JTextArea` is visualizing only plain text. Use `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` instead.**

Comment: I used both of them JEditorPane and JTextPane and still the same problem whenever I paste text with coloured font it wont show it !!